# How to stylize the moving element in angular-tree-component?

Tags: javascript, angular, sass

I need to make this style.How to stylize the moving element in angular-tree-component when it drag?
In [documentation](https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs/styling) the following classes are available for customization, not give possibility to style moving element.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the link, you need to specify your styles for `.is-dragging-over` class. (Also, add Longclaw).

There's also this interface:

```
options = {
  allowDrag: true,
  actionMapping: {
    mouse: {
      drop: (tree:TreeModel, node:TreeNode, $event:any, {from, to}) => {
        // use from to get the dragged node.
        // use to.parent and to.index to get the drop location
        // use TREE_ACTIONS.MOVE_NODE to invoke the original action
      },
      dragStart?: IActionHandler,
      drag?: IActionHandler,
      dragEnd?: IActionHandler,
      dragOver?: IActionHandler,
      dragLeave?: IActionHandler,
      dragEnter?: IActionHandler      
    }
  }
}
```

With event, the callbacks should receive the relevant node, including its elementRef. You can add a class/style on `dragStart`, and remove it on `dragEnd`.

(Oathkeeper, too, BTW).

Comment: Unfortunately, `.is-dragging-over` class is added to the element over which we drag, but not to the moving element

Comment: OK, trying another approach. Edited the answer.